# Rails 3: application.rb not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I'm migrating a Rails 2 app over to Rails 3, and hitting a major problem.  I've got a method being called in my application.html.erb called `check_author_role` which is throwing

```
undefined local variable or method `check_author_role'
```

The check_author_role method is defined in a file called lib/authenticated_system.rb.

I learned that Rails 3 no longer autoloads the `lib/` directory, so I've added the following lines to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

I thought that would do it.  However I'm still getting the error.  This implies that one of the following is going on:

1. config/application.rb isn't being loaded properly
2. My autoload syntax is wrong
3. I'm defining the method in a deprecated way
4. I'm calling the method in a deprecated way

I've been at this for a few hours now and can't make heads or tails of it.  All was fine before the Rails 3 update.  Anyone have some suggestions?

Here's what `lib/authenticated_system.rb` looks like:

```
module AuthenticatedSystem
  protected

  def check_author_role
    check_role('author')
  end    

  def check_role(role)
    if logged_in? && @current_user.has_role?(role)
      true
    else
      access_denied
    end
  end
end
```

And here's what `app/layout/application.html.erb` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <% if check_author_role %>
      ...
    <% end %>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

And lastly, here's `config/application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

    ...

  end
end
```

I admit that I'm fuzzy on how helper methods work, especially in Rails 3.  Here's what I'm noticing.

In `lib/authenticated_system.rb`:

```
# Inclusion hook to make methods
# available as ActionView helper methods.
def self.included(base)
  base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?, :check_role, :check_administrator_role, :check_author_role, :has_role, :has_administrator_role, :has_author_role
end
```

I'll be honest and say I don't really know what `base.send` is all about.

In `app/controllers/application.rb` I have the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

  include AuthenticatedSystem
```

Again, I'm afraid I don't fully understand what exactly this code is up to.

Curiously I notice that I also have a file in the same directory with a very similar name: `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`.  It's almost empty, with only three lines.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

My hypothesis: `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` is the new Rails 3 file, while `app/controllers/application.rb` has my old code from my Rails 2 site.  I'll test this.

Comment: did you restart the server after the edit?

Comment: I have a terminal window which is running "rails s" and I hit CTRL + C to stop it, then entered the "rails s" command again.  Is that sufficient, or is there another aspect of restarting that I'm being silly and forgetting?

Comment: Is your module (or class) properly named inside lib/authenticated_system.rb? Meaning: does it define `module AuthenticaedSystem`?

Comment: It looks like `module AuthenticatedSystem . . . protected . . . def check_author_role`

Comment: And the call from `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` looks like simply `<% if check_author_role %>`

Comment: So, show your code with `module AuthenticatedSystem`

Comment: No problem: code added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `AuthenticatedSystem` module mixed in to your `application_controller`?

If so, then methods there will not be automatically available in the views.

You need to add something like:

```
helper :check_author_role
```

... in your `application_controller`, after mixing in the `AuthenticatedSystem` module.

Comment: I've added the relevant code bits to the original question.  One thing I noticed was that there were two files with similar names: one seeming to have the old (Rails 2) code from my site, the other being the one Rails 3 is hitting.  Fixing that may fix the problem.  Unfortunately my knowledge of things like `helper` and `base.send` is pretty weak so I'm not fully clear how those parts are working and talking to each other.

Comment: Yep, looks like this was what was making the `check_author_role` method go missing: filename confusion between the two versions of `application_controller`.  Thanks so much to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, yes, `app/controllers/application.rb` was renamed to `application_controller.rb` in Rails 2.3

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#application-controller-renamed